# Excel VBA copy and paste based on Macro results

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that give me all the holidays based on a year I type in cell C2
and the results are in sheet1 range(c5:c14)
I want for example to create another macro in order to have all the holidays from 2015 to 2050 and copy all the results in sheet3 column A.
of course the results have to be order so I get all the years in column A.

Can you help me out with that please?

Thanks

Comment: You need to give more detail in your question, including a reproducible example and code you have tried. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a macro which reads a year from C2 and writes holidays to C5:C14. You tell us nothing about these 10 holidays so no one can help there. However, I assume this macro will generate the list of holidays you want for any year in the range 2015 to 2050.

Split this macro into two:

- Function `Macro1` which accepts a year as a parameter and returns an array of holidays.
- Sub `Macro2` which reads a year from C2, calls `Macro1` and writes the returned array to C5:C14.

Debug `Macro1` and `Macro2` as necessary.  You now have code that duplicates your original macro but with the holiday generating code as a sub-routine that can be called by a new macro.

Write Macro3 based on the following:

```
RowCrnt = 1
For Year = 2015 to 2050
  Holidays = Macro1(Year)
  For InxHol = LBound(Holiday) to UBound(Holiday)
    Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value = Holidays(InxHol)
    RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
  Next
Next
```

I think that will give you what you seek for minimum effort.